# Multiple certificate in SAML metadata xml file

Tags: ssl, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, digital-certificate

I am using SAML 2.0 for SSO in my application.
Currently i am using one certificate in metadata. So, at the time of certificate expiry. I have to change certificate at specific time i.e. at the time of certificate expire.
I need to support dual certificate support in metadata. So, I can add new certificate before the old gets expired.
How can i achieve this? 
Here is my existing medatadata file :

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- $Id: SPMetadata.xml 2936 2008-05-26 08:06:46Z jre $ -->
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="https://examplecom/sso/saml/metadata" xmlns:brs="http://www.eogs.dk/2007/07/brs" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
   <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false"  WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      <md:KeyDescriptor>
         <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate> 
               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX----My certificate which I am using------
               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
         </ds:KeyInfo>
      </md:KeyDescriptor>
      <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
      <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
      <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://examplecom/sso/saml/SAMLAssertionConsumer" index="0"/>
   </md:SPSSODescriptor>
   <md:Organization>
      <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="en">XXX example</md:OrganizationName>
      <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">XXX example</md:OrganizationDisplayName>
      <md:OrganizationURL xml:lang="en">http://www.examplecom</md:OrganizationURL>
   </md:Organization>
   <md:ContactPerson>
      <md:Company>XXX</md:Company>
      <md:GivenName>XXX Support</md:GivenName>
      <md:SurName>Support</md:SurName>
      <md:EmailAddress>mailto:saml-support@examplecom</md:EmailAddress>
      <md:TelephoneNumber>XXXXX</md:TelephoneNumber>
   </md:ContactPerson>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Athough XML Signature Syntax and Processing recommendation (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) referenced in SAML meta data spec would allow to specify several  elements within the `<ds:X509Data>` element, the SAMLv2 interoperability profile  (e.g. http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-metadata-iop-cs-01.html, section 2.5.1) suggests to use multiple `<ds:KeyInfo>` elements within `<md:KeyDescriptor>` elements.

Comment: Can i have multiple `<X509Certificate>` tag in metadata file?

Comment: According to XML Signature Syntax and Processing recommendation this would be allowed, but most SAML SP/IdP do not support this as they are mostly follow the recommendations given in the SAMLv2 interoperability profile

E.g. https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-10330

Answer (score 2):

You can have zero or more KeyDescriptor elements as defined in [the standard](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf) so just go ahead and add a new

```
 <md:KeyDescriptor> 
     <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>                     
           <ds:X509Certificate>
                  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
           </ds:X509Certificate> 
        </ds:X509Data> 
     </ds:KeyInfo> 
  </md:KeyDescriptor>
```

below the existing one.